# cross checking with mysql and path

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash, centos

I'm trying to cross check to see if the filenames I have is in the database listing I have. If it's not, then delete it. I'm missing a few key points, please help me learn this through, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFSTEMP=$IFS
IFS=\^



     rarFile=`find -name '*.mp4'`

       for r in $rarFile
        do
    filename=$(basename "$r")

    echo "$filename"

    myvariable=$(echo "SELECT nctid FROM $SQL_DATABASE.$SQL_TABLE WHERE nctid=$filname" | mysql -h$SQL_HOST -u$SQL_USERNAME -p$SQL_PASSWORD -N  $SQL_DATABASE)

    if(!$myvariable) {
    rm -rf $r
    }
    done


IFS="$IFSTEMP"
```

Comment: What points are you missing? What is your output vs. your expected output?

Comment: Do you want this functionality with PHP code ?

Comment: what does this $ sign before echo means `myvariable=$(echo`

Comment: Hello, @MichaelRobinson it doesn't output anything as my code is not complete.

Comment: @Mr.Alien from what I'm reading online, it gives me the output of my select statement

Comment: @HirenSoni It doesnt have to have php, bash alone is fine if it does what i need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$myvariable = "SELECT ...";` it should be like this

Comment: Hello, I'm not having issues with pulling out the variables thus far. It's my lack of understanding with bash that i can't seem to cross check with what's in the folder against the db and then delete it.

Comment: Why are you changing IFS ? Furthermore last statement should be IFS="$IFSTEMP"

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I am not sure. It seems like the last help I got always had that. shall I remove it?

Comment: Till this very day, I am still unable to do a cross check for the filenames I have in a folder with a column inside a mysql tables with filenames as well. I just pretty much want to delete local all filenames that is not in the mysql table.

I really wish someone could shine the light on this mater for me. I am extremely weak. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IFS is the delimiter used by the shell to split arguments, changing it is not recommended, here apparently there is no reason to change it. Default is ' \t\n'

to see the difference :

```
(x='a b^c';IFS=\ $'\t\n';for s in $x;do echo $s;done)
(x='a b^c';IFS=^;for s in $x;do echo $s;done)
```

more information :

```
man bash
/IFS
```